# Concourse git resource triggering

Tags: cloud-foundry, concourse

Hi I have a concourse deployment process that deploys to cloudfoundry whenever I tag a release with specific keywords.

This works well for new versions because the git resource picks up the newly tagged commits and checks the tag using the tag_filter option.

The problem is when I want to roll back to a previous version. How can I force the git resource to pick up on particular older commit that it has already used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the git resource in question, and then turn off the versions ahead of the one you are trying to trigger with.

[image: how to turn off resource versions]
Now you can manually trigger the job that would normally get automatically triggered, and it should re-run with the old version.